# Do ALL iOS .p12 certs require a password?

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, p12

We are working on building push notifications, however the app owner states that there is no CERT PW for their .p12 app cert.  From all our experiences, there is ALWAYS an associated cert password.  Anyone see otherwise?

Comment: This sounds confused. There is no such thing as a "cert pw". A p12 is a file exported from your keychain, and yes you can leave the password blank if you like. The reason for giving it a password is that it contains the private key.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, .p12 must have some password for securing it. But we can leave password field empty and hit return/enter while exporting .p12 from keychain. So in that case, no password means hit retrun/enter by leaving password field empty while using .p12 for sending push.

Answer (score 0):

Password for .p12 is optional. You can either choose one while exporting or leave it empty.